How can I configure "do not disturb" so that Telegram still emits some sound when someone calls?
How can I configure "do not disturb" so that Telegram still emits some sound when someone calls?
I tried to configure as follows up, but when someone calls me on Telegram the phone doesn't make any sound (it does show some visual notification of the Telegram though):


In Telegram:

I have a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra running Android 13.
